# Spring Security RunAsManagerImpl doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have Bean_1 which call method from Bean_2. Bean_1 has following security configuration:

```
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* com.proficiency.cg.core.blc.Bean_1.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_Administrators,RUN_AS_InternalRole"/>
```

Bean_2 - has following security configuration:

```
<protect-pointcut expression="execution(* com.proficiency.cg.core.blc.Bean_2.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_InternalRole"/>
```

In additional - I set up the RunAsManager:

```
<b:bean id="runAsManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.intercept.RunAsManagerImpl">
  <b:property name="key" value="prof_key"/>
</b:bean>

<b:bean id="runAsAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.intercept.RunAsImplAuthenticationProvider">
  <b:property name="key" value="prof_key"/>
</b:bean>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" run-as-manager-ref="runAsManager" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
```

When I run my test program - I get security exception while access to Bean_2.
Conclusion: RunAsManager - doesn't work properly or atoll.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. looks like RunAsManager has a bug. While debug - I found following in implementation of original RunAsManagerImpl:

```
public Authentication buildRunAs(Authentication authentication, Object object,
        Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> newAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (ConfigAttribute attribute : attributes) {
        if (this.supports(attribute)) {
            GrantedAuthority extraAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                    getRolePrefix() + attribute.getAttribute());
            newAuthorities.add(extraAuthority);
        }
    }
```

Everything looks good, but... 
this method run over all attributes (ROLE_Administrators,RUN_AS_InternalRole) and check is the string starts with "RUN_AS_". 
If yes - (this.supports(...)) - create new GrantedAuthority (getRolePrefix() + attribute.getAttribute()). 
Everything is good, but getRolePrefix() returns "ROLE_". In fact - it creates new GrantedAuthority something like : ROLE_RUN_AS_InternalRole - which is not exists!
As a solution - I created my own RunAsManagerImpl which overwrite this method and just cut of "RUN_AS" from attribute before create new GrantedAuthority 
I hope this will be fixed in next version.